# Find number of records shown in the current page

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

How can I find the number of records shown in the current page in jqGrid. I only want the currently displayed page of the pager.

Comment: So, the number of records that the user can currently see on their screen?  Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: No, the current page in the pager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return the current # of rows on a given page and WILL work correctly if you are using grouping, subgrid or summary footer.

```
$("#your-grid").getGridParam("reccount")
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never used jqgrid, but based on what I'm seeing on [this demo page](http://jqgrid.com/jqgrid/demos/jqgrid-standalone/working-with-row-data), it looks like you could just get the number of `.jqgrow`'s. Is this what you are looking for?

```
$(".jqgrow").size();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XPv4N/) (console will show "10")

Comment: This will not work correctly if you use summary rows, grouping, or subgrids. Take a look at my answer below for the correct way to get the record count on a given page.